# How to install mcrypt on MAMP 3.0.6 for Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, mamp, mcrypt

I use the MAMP */php.ini file as the config file for both web and CLI access to php and now that I've upgrade to MAMP 3.0.6 with php 5.5.14 Laravel/Artisan crashes claiming no mcrypt support. How can I either downgrade to MAMP 3.0.5,where it worked, or fix MAMP 3.0.6.

MAMP environment is osX 10.9.4, Laravel 4 and the fix at /topicdesk.com/downloads/mcrypt/mcrypt-downloads doesn't work for me as it tries to download an old version of mcrypt.so

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when I updated from 3.0.5 to 3.0.6 and after a little digging realized that the command line was pointed toward Mavericks' version of PHP and not MAMP's version. (You can check which by running `which php` and seeing what's returned.)

To fix it, all I needed to do add the MAMP version of PHP to my path (probably easiest to do that in your bash profile) and then it started looking at MAMP's version of PHP by default (which has mcrypt enabled by default).